# Pass in class object to usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

Hi how do i pass in a class object from UI Form to the user control datagridview?

I created a user control which it has a datagridview, a search textbox on top of datagridview, and a label to show total count. and i would like to have the following feature to be written in that control.

- Show Total count for that object bounded to datagridview.
- TextChange event to filter the data in datagridview.

I would like the above features to be written in Usercontrol as i felt it is redundant to repeat that in UI Form.
For this, I created a datasource in the usercontrol

```
 public object Datasource { get; set; }
```

1) If my class object is e.g. `User`, how do i get the type of the datasource converted to User and get the Count of total User and bind to the label in the usercontrol?

2) I felt it redundant to write this below in every form. How do i simplify this and make this run in the userControl itself by using the datasource i pass in to it.

```
 private void BaseCRUDForm_GridViewTextChangedSearch(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (sender.ToString().Length > 0)
        {
            Users = Users.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(sender.ToString())).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            Users = Repository.UserRespository(false).GetAllUsers();
        }
        UserBindingSource.DataSource = Users;
    }
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

While creating the object of user control, There are two ways to forward the data in user control

1. Initialize the property. The Property will have the object type which can be cased later while binding to grid.
2. pass the data to constructor.

I feel that you should have constructor i.e point 2.

Now after casting this object, you can populate the label as well as the grid.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: But how do i get the type of the object? Could you show me an example?

Comment: Suppose following is the generic class.                       public class generics
{
public int a;
public string str;
}  Suppose the user control class is below public class Userctl
{
private object aa;
public Userctl(object  a)
{
aa = a;
if(aa.GetType().Name.Equals("generics"))
{
generics g = (generics) aa;
grid.datasource = g;
}
}
    } Now in the main form you are populating the data in generic class  generics g = new generics();
g.str = "test1";
g.a = 1;
and below is the instance of user control  Userctl c = new Userctl(g);          Please let me know in case of any confusion.

Comment: What are your comments about it?